# Configure firebase functions to use a service account for deploying

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

When looking at the docs for cloud functions it shows an option to deploy the function using a service account instead of having it run with the [default service account](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#adding_a_user-managed_service_account_at_deployment):

```
gcloud functions deploy <function> --service-account <service_account_email>
```

Is there is a way in firebase to configure it to deploy a function using a service account when running `firebase deploy`?

I've tried doing a straight-forward dumb approach of adding it to the `.firebaserc` file, but I don't know if that is supported or what the correct syntax would be:

```json
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "<project>"
  },
  "targets": {
    "<project>": {
      "functions": {
        "service-account": "<...>@<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the service account the firebase function is deployed with using the [RunTime options interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.runtimeoptions.md#properties). For example:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const myfunc = functions.runWith({serviceAccount:"sa@goog.com"}).https.onCall(async (request, context) => {
}
```

When you use the firebase cli without any additional parameters, the function should be deployed with the specified service account.

`firebase deploy --only functions:myfunc`

If done correctly, you will see that the Service Account in the details section of the function is changed to the specified service account.